# Paper by I. Swanson on symbolic powers

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, reference-request

I am looking for a paper by Irena Swanson on a result on comparison of ordinary and symbolic powers of prime ideals in complete local rings.
The paper is referenced in problem 0.9 here
https://aimath.org/WWN/integralclosure/Huneke.pdf
I don't know the name of the paper, and so far my searches have been to no avail. I searched through the preprints made available on her website, but did not find it (or probably missed it).
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be number 11 on her paper site "Linear equivalence of topologies".

As for Problem 0.9, it is known for regular local rings over fields by Ein-Lazarsfeld-Smith and Hochster-Huneke. The most recent result is for isolated singularities, see the paper Craig Huneke. Daniel Katz. Javid Validashti. "Uniform equivalence of symbolic and adic topologies." Illinois J. Math. 53 (1) 325 - 338, [DOI:10.1215/ijm/1264170853](https://doi.org/10.1215/ijm/1264170853) (a pdf file can be found on Dan Katz website).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Hailong for the pointed reference. I am aware of Ein-Lazarsfeld-Smith and Hochster-Huneke results in this direction. I had not seen the Huneke-Katz-Validashti paper though. Thanks for that one as well.